# Block specific url on all browsers

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, url

I have a "kiosk" computer with *IE* and *Chrome* installed. 
With firewall hardware I denied web navigation except for some domains.

Now I need to block only a specific section of a site, say `www.google.com/a/b`, while the top domain `www.google.com` must be accessible and I can't do it with firewall.

I know that I can do it with Content Advisor on IE, but they have also Chrome and I don't like to use extensions. Is there another "low level" way to reach my goal?

I can't use products like Privoxy or similar. Only Windows "native" components.
Thank you

Comment: This can't be done without extensions in Chrome

Comment: Ok, in fact my question is if there is something at Windows level that can block both browsers.

Comment: You need [this](http://www.currentware.com/browsecontrol/)

Comment: If the URL's are secure, then the OS will never even see the path. This is why it would need to be done at the browser level, before the connection is encrypted.

Comment: Can this be done in the hosts file?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing Windows' HOSTS file:

1. Open Notepad as Administrator on the computer you wish to block the url on
2. In Notepad, click 'File' in the top left corner of the application, then from the drop-down click 'Open'
3. Navigate to Windows Drive\system32\drivers\etc, look for the 'hosts' file and open it
4. If you haven't changed your HOSTS file in the past, it should look like [this](http://www.guidingtech.com/assets/postimages/2010/08/20100804B04.png). From there, go to the bottom of the hosts file and create a new line. Then type 127.0.0.1 website.com/subdirectory (Change to whatever you want to block)
5. After finished, save the file by going back to 'File' then from the drop-down 'Save'. Then open either browser and type in the website you blocked to make sure it isn't accessible.

Comment: The HOSTS file can only relocate hostnames (domain). You cannot specify a path. `example.org` works while `example.org/path/to/somewhere` does not.